# Синтаксическая ошибка в первой строке

Tags: python, список

Здравствуйте.

Это моя первая программа. Подскажите плиз почему в первой строке возникает синтаксическая ошибка? Всё вроде корректно записано..

```
num=[1,2,3]
x=int(input("plz enter the number from one to three:"))
if x==num[0]:
    print(x "is first number")
elif x==num[1]:
    print(x " is second nuber")
elif x==num[2]:
    print (x " is third")
else:
    print ("wrong number")
print("the end")
```

В первой строке ошибка:  SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Корректно записана программа, возможно еще какие-то ошибки есть?? 
Спасибо.

Comment: В первой строке ошибки нет, а вот в принтах вы запятые между аргументами забыли

Comment: Вот поэтому нужно стек трассы прикладывать, а то пишут ошибка в первой строке, а оказывается что в 4-й :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас в функции `print()` ошибка, так как необходимо суммировать х со строкой. 
Например `print(x + "is first number")` или можно вообще `print("%s is first number" % x)`